# Eliminating Numbers Greater Than X

Tags: combinatorics

If you have a range of numbers from 1-49 with 6 numbers to choose from, of the nearly 14 million possible combinations, how many combinations are there left if you eliminate all combinations containing a "greater than" specified value for each of the 6 numbers? Example:

a1 = 11

a2 = 20

a3 = 28

a4 = 35

a5 = 42

a6 = 49

"a1", 13, 22, 25, 31, 42 (Any combination where the value of the first number is greater than "a1" is eliminated from the 14 million combinations. Let's say 2 million combinations were eliminated, now only 12 million combinations are left)

11, "a2", 22, 25, 31, 42 (Again, any combination where the value of the second number is greater than "a2" will also be eliminated from the 12 million remaining combinations. Let's say another 2 million combinations were eliminated, now there are only 10 million left)

Repeat through to a6.

By eliminating all combinations greater than a1 through a6 from the 14 million combinations, how many combinations remain?

Comment: "Like all lotteries, the same number must not repeat in a selection of 6 numbers and the numbers must be in increasing order. " The numbers must be in increasing order isn't the norm for lotteries.

Comment: Are numbers $a_1$ to $a_6$ in increasing order?

Comment: What I mean to say is there are 13,983,816 combinations - permutations are excluded. Lottery numbers are presented in ascending order - that is what I meant. I'm looking to calculate the remaining combinations if a1 to a6 are eliminated when presented in ascending order like all lotteries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate this by a recursion. Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of permitted choices of the first $n$ numbers if the $n$th number is equal to $k$.  You have

- $f(n,k)=f(n,k-1)+f(n-1,k-1)$ when $k \le a_k$
- $f(n,k)=0$ when $k \gt a_k$
- $f(n,0)=0$ when $n \gt 0$
- $f(0,k)=0$ when $k \gt 0$
- $f(0,0)=1$

You then want $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{49} f(6,k)$

With $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)=(49,49,49,49,49,49)$ you get $13983816$ for the final sum

With $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)=(11,20,28,35,42,49)$ you get $7458913$ for the final sum

Comment: Its kind of a brute force solution iterating through all the possibilities.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Perhaps 300 calculations or fewer rather than the 14 million real brute force might require

Comment: @Cannon444 - You just set up an array with $n$ running from $0$ to $6$ and $k$ from $0$ to $49$ Fill it with zeros.  Then let $f(0,0)=1$.  Then loop through the main recursion. It should run in less than a second - it was apparently instant in Excel